# Extracting code which has return statement to separate function

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a bit of code which is used in both functions, but the code which I want to move to separate function has a return statement, how can I achieve this

```
 private fun handleFlingCompleteFailure(failure: Failure) {
    Timber.d("Failure caught when using fling complete $failure")
    val order = orderStorage.fOrder ?: return // 1 - move 
    val currentStatus: String = order.status // 2 - move

    val logTimed = LogMapTimed("Acraft Flling Complete (partial: $view?.isPartiallyComplete)")

    fllingCompleteUseCaseError(logTimed, "$failure", currentStatus)
}

private fun handleFllingCompleteSuccess(response: FlOrderCompleteResponse) {
    val logTimed = LogMapTimed("Acraft Flling Complete (partial: $view?.partiallyComplete)")
    val order = orderStorage.flOrder ?: return //1 - move
    val currentStatus: String = order.status. //2 - move

    if (response.success) {
        fllingCompleteResponse(response, order, logTimed, currentStatus)
    } else {
        fllingCompleteUseCaseError(logTimed, "response - $response.success", currentStatus)
    }
}
```

what I want to do is

```
   private fun getCurrentOrderStatus(): String {
        val order = orderStorage.flOrder ?: return
        val currentStatus: String = order.status
        
        return currentStatus
    }
```

but how can I manage the return statement for the order

please suggest how can I do this

thanks
R

Comment: Your broken out function can return a nullable Pair, but in my opinion that's uglier than this trivial amount of code repetition.

Answer (score 0):

You can return Nullable String from extracted method:

```
private fun getCurrentOrderStatus(): String? {
    val order = orderStorage.flOrder ?: return null
    val currentStatus: String = order.status

    return currentStatus
}
```

And use elvis operator to fast return from client function:

```
private fun handleFlingCompleteFailure(failure: Failure) {
    Timber.d("Failure caught when using fling complete $failure")
    val currentStatus: String = getCurrentOrderStatus() ?: return
  
    // all other
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for that, but only question is `handleFllingCompleteSuccess` is using fllingCompleteResponse(response, order, logTimed, currentStatus) which requires `order`, if we move that to separate method `handleFllingCompleteSuccess` will not have access to it

Comment: As an option, you can create either read-only (if order can be changed with time) or single-time computed (if order is const while instance of the class with posted methods lives) property order that returns/keeps order from the `orderStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new function, it has no control over the flow of the function that called it, so it can't force the caller to return. The caller has to manage that itself, by checking the result and deciding whether to return early.

Your other problem is that you want to return two values, because if your calling function *doesn't* return early, it has some work to do, and it needs multiple variables to do it.

Here's a couple of approaches you could take, if you want to do this:

First up, you can create a result type, which **either** gives you both pieces of data, **or** an error type (or just null, which is what I'm gonna do)

```
data class OrderData(val order: SomeType, val currentStatus: String)

private fun getCurrentOrderStatus(): OrderData? {
    // this could be an expression instead of using return
    return orderStorage.flOrder?.let { OrderData(it, it.flOrder) }
}
```

Then you can use it in your calling function

```
private fun handleFllingCompleteSuccess(response: FlOrderCompleteResponse) {
    val logTimed = LogMapTimed("Acraft Flling Complete (partial: $view?.partiallyComplete)")
    val orderData = getCurrentOrderStatus()
    // early return - do it however you like, use a let block if you want
    if (orderData == null) return

    // smart casting means if it isn't null, it's definitely an OrderData with all the values
    if (response.success) {
        fllingCompleteResponse(response, orderData.order, logTimed, orderData.currentStatus)
    } else {
        fllingCompleteUseCaseError(logTimed, "response - $response.success", orderData.currentStatus)
    }
}
```

That's still requiring you to handle the early return yourself, but honestly that's logic the caller should be handling itself - what to do if the data isn't available

---

Another approach you could take is the functional one, pass in a function to invoke **if** the data is available.

```
private fun getCurrentOrderStatus(onSuccess: (WhateverFlOrderIs, String) -> Unit) {
    // same as before, except we're extracting the data and calling
    // the passed function with it - if flOrder is null we do nothing
     orderStorage.flOrder?.let { onSuccess(it, it.currentStatus) }
}
```

Now you can do this instead:

```
private fun handleFllingCompleteSuccess(response: FlOrderCompleteResponse) {
    val logTimed = LogMapTimed("Acraft Flling Complete (partial: $view?.partiallyComplete)")
    getCurrentOrderStatus() { order, currentStatus ->
        if (response.success) {
            fllingCompleteResponse(response, order, logTimed, currentStatus)
        } else {
            fllingCompleteUseCaseError(logTimed, "response - $response.success", currentStatus)
        }
    }
}
```

This way, your `getCurrentOrderStatus` function returns nothing anyway, so there's nothing to check and no early returning to do. Your caller just invokes it, passes it a function to run if it can, and that's the end of the method anyway.